# I want to use UI button to shoot the bullet , right now it is working fine with space key. I am not able to convert it to UI button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine

This is the script taken from the tanks asset store and I want to convert the shooting which is currently being done by space bar to Ui Shoot button. It should fire the bullet.
Like I want that when my button is pressed it should charge as to how much velocity is imparted to the bullet and it soon as I release it the bullet should be fired.
Also, I was thinking of a fill image which can show that thing in the button as well.

```
public class TankShooting: MonoBehaviour
{

    //public int m_PlayerNumber = 1;              // Used to identify the different players.
    public Rigidbody m_Shell;                   // Prefab of the shell.
    public Transform m_FireTransform;           // A child of the tank where the shells are spawned.
    public Slider m_AimSlider;                  // A child of the tank that displays the current launch force.
    //public AudioSource m_ShootingAudio;         // Reference to the audio source used to play the shooting audio. NB: different from the movement audio source.
    //public AudioClip m_ChargingClip;            // Audio that plays when each shot is charging up.
    //public AudioClip m_FireClip;                // Audio that plays when each shot is fired.
    public float m_MinLaunchForce = 15f;        // The force is given to the shell if the fire button is not held.
    public float m_MaxLaunchForce = 30f;        // The force is given to the shell if the fire button is held for the max charge time.
    public float m_MaxChargeTime = 0.75f;       // How long the shell can charge for before it is fired at max force.


    private string m_FireButton;                // The input axis that is used for launching shells.
    private float m_CurrentLaunchForce;         // The force that will be given to the shell when the fire button is released.
    private float m_ChargeSpeed;                // How fast the launch force increases, based on the max charge time.
    private bool m_Fired;                       // Whether or not the shell has been launched with this button press.
    private float nextFireTime;




    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // When the tank is turned on, reset the launch force and the UI
        m_CurrentLaunchForce = m_MinLaunchForce;
        m_AimSlider.value = m_MinLaunchForce;
    }


    private void Start ()
    {
        // The fire axis is based on the player number.
        m_FireButton = "Fire1"; //+ m_PlayerNumber;



        // The rate that the launch force charges up is the range of possible forces by the max charge time.
        m_ChargeSpeed = (m_MaxLaunchForce - m_MinLaunchForce) / m_MaxChargeTime;
    }


    public void Update()
    {
        // The slider should have a default value of the minimum launch force.
        m_AimSlider.value = m_MinLaunchForce;

        // If the max force has been exceeded and the shell hasn't yet been launched...
        if (m_CurrentLaunchForce >= m_MaxLaunchForce && !m_Fired)
        {
            // ... use the max force and launch the shell.
            m_CurrentLaunchForce = m_MaxLaunchForce;
            Fire (m_CurrentLaunchForce, 1);
        }
        // Otherwise, if the fire button has just started being pressed...
        else if (Input.GetButtonDown (m_FireButton))
        {
            // ... reset the fired flag and reset the launch force.
            m_Fired = false;
            m_CurrentLaunchForce = m_MinLaunchForce;

            // Change the clip to the charging clip and start it playing.
            //m_ShootingAudio.clip = m_ChargingClip;
            //m_ShootingAudio.Play ();
        }
        // Otherwise, if the fire button is being held and the shell hasn't been launched yet...
        else if (Input.GetButton (m_FireButton) && !m_Fired)
        {
            // Increment the launch force and update the slider.
            m_CurrentLaunchForce += m_ChargeSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            m_AimSlider.value = m_CurrentLaunchForce;
        }
        // Otherwise, if the fire button is released and the shell hasn't been launched yet...
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp (m_FireButton) && !m_Fired)
        {
            // ... launch the shell.
            Fire (m_CurrentLaunchForce, 1);

        }
    }


    public void Fire (float launchForce, float fireRate)
    {
        if (Time.time > nextFireTime) 
        {
            nextFireTime = Time.time + fireRate;
            // Set the fired flag so only Fire is only called once.
            m_Fired = true;

            // Create an instance of the shell and store a reference to it's rigidbody.
            Rigidbody shellInstance =
                Instantiate (m_Shell, m_FireTransform.position, m_FireTransform.rotation) as Rigidbody;

            // Set the shell's velocity to the launch force in the fire position's forward direction.
            shellInstance.velocity = m_CurrentLaunchForce * m_FireTransform.forward; 

            // Change the clip to the firing clip and play it.
            //m_ShootingAudio.clip = m_FireClip;
            //m_ShootingAudio.Play ();

            // Reset the launch force.  This is a precaution in case of missing button events.
            m_CurrentLaunchForce = m_MinLaunchForce;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You just need an on hold event to the button. I made a package which can handle many type of button events you can check it here: https://github.com/Menyus777/RedFox-Smart-Button

Answer (score 0):

There is Very Easy Solution for this:

Create A Function In Your Script

> ShootTheBullet()

and The Create A UI Button and Click on Add Button In your Button's Component Event

> "On Click"

Drag and Drop The gameObject that you have attached your C# script From Hierarchey that Contains "ShootTheBullet()" and then click On Right Option Select your Script an Select That Function.

Now you are ready to Shoot Bullets With UI Button.

Comment: I have tried this method of implementing the UI buttons but it did not work for me

Comment: Okay, show me screenshot of Unity Editor where you have assigned the function and also show me your Function "ShootTheBulet()" in code. then i'il able to solve your problem